# Displaying a value in a populated combo box

Tags: c#

Here is the situation:
I have populated a combo box with the names of divisions in my company and it is working fine. I go into edit mode and pull one record out of the data table so I bind all controls on the form with one record. I also populate this combo box with all divisions but want it to display the selected division. While I know how to display correct date in textbox controls, I do not know how to make combo box display only selected data. It displays the first record from the query which populates it. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not clear if you are using ASP.NET or Windows Form.  I am assuming Windows Form at the moment since it has an actual ComboBox control, while ASP.NET only has DropDownList (not counting the AJAX Control Toolkit).

ComboBox has a bunch of Selected... properties, i.e. SelectedIndex, SelectedItem, SelectedValue, SelectedText that you can manipulate (set) to show a certain item on the screen.  So you can just do cbDivision.SelectedText = myRecord.Division (assuming Division in myRecord contains the same name as the one bound in the ComboBox.

for reference, see: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear! I am indeed using Windows form. So in my dataset which has only one record, division column has a value which was originally saved from a value selected from the combo box. I would like to search the combo box for division name in the dataset and display it so the user knows the previously saved division name before changing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly. But I think you just want to display the selectedValue in the dropdown list populated from a list of values.

< asp:DropDownList DataTextField="SomeDecsription" DataValueField="SomeValue" ...... />

I apologise if this is not what you were asking for

Comment: Please see my response to Jimmy above.